# type conversion with strict_types in PHP

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

Why does this code terminate without any issues?
I thought it would output a TypeError Exception because an Integer cannot be casted or converted to float cause of the declaration of strict_types.

```
?php
declare(strict_types=1);
function multiply(float $a, float $b): float {
    return (double)$a * (double)$b;
}
$six = multiply(2, 3);
echo gettype($six);

//output: double
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is possible to enable strict mode on a per-file basis. In strict mode, only a variable of exact type of the type declaration will be accepted, or a `TypeError` will be thrown. **The only exception to this rule is that an integer may be given to a function expecting a float.**
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict

It's [allowed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5#behaviour_of_strict_type_checks) as a [*widening primitive conversion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value.